# Laravel 5.6 session timeout exception when using spatie permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission

I have been trying to redirect the user after session timeout, but when using spatie permissions package i cant get the TokenMismatchException for the session timeout, i always get UnauthorizedException. Here is my Exceptions/Handler.php file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException){


        session()->flash('warning','Session timeout. Please login again.');
        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }



    if ($exception instanceof \Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException){


        return redirect('/restricted');
    }



    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

How to catch the session timeout exception and make a custom redirect in this case?

Comment: try \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException instead of TokenMismatchException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the package's `RoleMiddleware` is being evaluated before `VerifyCsrfToken` in the pipeline. From their source, you can see it throws an `UnauthorizedException` immediately if the user is not logged in:

```
namespace Spatie\Permission\Middlewares;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException;
class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            throw UnauthorizedException::notLoggedIn();
        }
        $roles = is_array($role)
            ? $role
            : explode('|', $role);
        if (! Auth::user()->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
            throw UnauthorizedException::forRoles($roles);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You can modify the order of middleware by setting the `$middlewarePriority` property in the kernel, however, be aware this can lead to unintended side effects:

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
];
```

Look at the order of middleware defined in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` and work off that.